# Django passing a variable to Httpresponseredirect throws exception

Tags: python, django

The problem I Have right now is that I get a :

Reverse for 'documentation' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

when I try to redirect to another view using HttpResponseRedirect

Here is my urls.py

```
    url(r'^documentation/([0-9])/$', views.documents, name='documentation'),
```

here my views.py

```
def view1(request):

  if request.method == 'POST':
      profe = request.POST.get('value')

      a = value.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
      b = int(a)
      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('documentation', args=(b,)))

  else:

      return render(request, "anhtml.html", info)

def documents(request,valor):
      ...something...
      return render(request, "anotherhtml.html", ..something..)
```

Thanks

template (anhtml.html)

```
...
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for p in ps %}
        <tr>
            <td><button id="boton1" button type="submit" name = "valor" value ="{{p.idp}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">{{p.nombre}} {{p.apellido}}</button>
            </td>
            <td>algo</a> </td>
        </tr>
        {%endfor%}
    </form>
```

Comment: What is the url you are trying to visit when you get the error?

Comment: The main idea is that I get redirected to http://127.0.0.1:8000/documentation/1 but it doesn´t. 
If a paste that url directly in the browser i get redirected succesfully. So I now for sure that the regex works fine

Comment: What action is triggering the error? It might be helpful to show your template code.

Comment: just added my template form, it really isn´t much more complex than that

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with the HttpResponseRedirect, but with the call to reverse().

When you pass args, you should use the list notation for the values:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('documentation', args=[b]))
```

That should help, at least.

Comment: You don't need the `,` for a 1 item list. Also, it won't hurt for OP to try this, but I have always used tuples instead of lists for the `args` argument without issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this didn´t made the trick, but still was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add arguments to Your view

Just Change

def view1(request):

to

def view1(request, p):

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).